# Random number max/min with limit

Tags: jquery

I would like to incorporate a `limit` variable to cap the random number generated using the `Math.floor()` formula. The function currently chooses a number between `min` and `max` but I want to be able to put a limit or ceiling on the generated number `var limit= 12;`. The number can be a maximum of the available quantity but no more than the limit.

```js
$(".item").each(function() {
  var t = $(this);
  var max = parseFloat($(this).find(".available").text());
  var min = 1;
  var limit = 12;
  var qty = $(".qty");

  function generateRandomInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }

  t.find(qty).val(generateRandomInteger(min, max));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="available">50</div>
  <input readonly class="qty"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="available">70</div>
  <input readonly class="qty"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="available">40</div>
  <input readonly class="qty"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add new information to your question post, not in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the value of max to the value of limit when max is bigger then the limit.

```js
$(".item").each(function() {
  var t = $(this);
  var max = parseFloat($(this).find(".available").text());
  var min = 1;
  var limit = 12;
  var qty = $(".qty");
  
  max = max > limit ? limit : max;

  function generateRandomInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }

  t.find(qty).val(generateRandomInteger(min, max));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="available">50</div>
  <input readonly class="qty"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="available">70</div>
  <input readonly class="qty"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="available">40</div>
  <input readonly class="qty"></div>
</div>
```